# i am getting error on post method ionic(6) with capacitor angular(13)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqaXE.png)vendor.js:139831 ERROR
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/checkEmailExists", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/checkEmailExists: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:8080/checkEmailExists"
**proto**: HttpResponseBase

Comment: See the 'Info' warning from the img, try what it says there and see if it works.

Comment: you need to set base url

Comment: Yeah already set base url